# Compile C++11 with cython

Tags: c++11, cython

I have some cpp files that I would like to use in python. I tried to compile it with cython, however I'm getting some errors.It's worth noticing the cpp code compiles fine in the same machine with CXX flags set.

For instance, the following constructor gives me an error:

```
error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
affine(float _angle,float _tilt):angle{_angle},tilt{_tilt}{}
```

Can someone provide an example of how to set this up using Cython?

Thanks.

Comment: What errors ? What does the code that produces them look like ?

Comment: That error just looks that you are missing ; after {}